# Memory leaks while opening the sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Following  methods gets called from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,when I run on Instruments **openDatabase** method causing leaks..
please suggest me how to clear

```
- (NSString*)getdestinationPath {
    NSArray *pathsArray=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *doumentDirectoryPath=[pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *destinationPath=[doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataBaseName];
    NSLog(@"database path %@",destinationPath);
    return destinationPath;
}




- (void)chkAndCreateDatbase {
    NSFileManager *fileManger=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *destinationPath=[self getdestinationPath];
    if ([fileManger fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]){
        //NSLog(@"database localtion %@",destinationPath);
        return;
    }
    NSString *sourcePath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataBaseName];
    [fileManger copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];
}





- (void)openDatabase {
    path=[self getdestinationPath];
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK) // here leak is showing
    {
        NSLog(@"dataBaseOpen");
    }
    else {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSLog(@"dataBaseNotOpen");  
    }   
}
```

Comment: whenever I call to database this method gets called.Responsible frame is sqlite3MemMalloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are leaking because you're not calling `sqlite3_close(database)`
 when you get `SQLITE_OK`.

```
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK) 
{
    NSLog(@"dataBaseOpen");
    // leak happens here, do stuff then call sqlite3_close(database), or move it out of the if/else block.

}
else {
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSLog(@"dataBaseNotOpen");  
}
```